# Function to call Login API using axios (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a full stack web application using React JS and Spring. I have created an API for Login.

```
@PostMapping("/users/login")
    public Status loginUser(@Valid @RequestBody PortalUser user) {
        List<PortalUser> users = userRepository.findAll();
        for (PortalUser other : users) {
            if (other.equals(user)) {
                
                return Status.SUCCESS;
            }
        }
        return Status.FAILURE;
    }
```

This API checks if user has entered correct login credentials or not. If yes, then it returns Enum as "SUCCESS" and if not then it returns Enum as "FAILURE".

The web API works fine on Postman. I now want to call the same from my frontend but I am unable to do so. Could anyone help me out with the same?

```
const user_base_url = "http://localhost:8080/users";

class CustomerService{

    authenticateUser(user) {
        return axios.post(user_base_url+ '/login', user);
    }
}
```

I have created this function to call the API using axios.

```
validateUser = () => {

        let user = { 

            username: this.state.email, 
            password: this.state.password
        };
        
        authenticateUser(user);
```

I am unable to proceed after this.

I basically want to authenticate the User when the login button (the Validate User function is called) is pressed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain: "I am unable to do so"... why? It throws an error? which error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
const user_base_url = "http://localhost:8080/users";

class CustomerService{

    authenticateUser(user) {
        return axios.post(user_base_url+ '/login', user)
         .then((res)=>{
           if(res.data === 'SUCCESS') {
             //user logged in
           } else if(res.data === 'FAILURE') {
             //login failed
           }})
         .catch(err) {
           console.error(err)
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing console.log(res) inside then callback, you will get an idea of what's coming from the API response.